# How to limit CPU usage for some specific processes

Tags: ubuntu, process, cpu, process-management, cpu-usage

Saying that I have a program, which will fork three sub-processes, meaning that it will create four processes in total while running.

My ubuntu server has 16 CPUs.

Is it possible to assign the CPU resources to the four processes?

For example, I force the four processes to execute on one CPU, or I force the process A and B to execute on one CPU and C and D to execute on another CPU?

I've heard a tool named `cpulimit` but I don't think it can help me.

Comment: That's called [setting the process's CPU affinity](https://www.google.com/search?q=set+processor+affinity+ubuntu).

Comment: Check out this post about taskset: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33994983/assigning-a-cpu-core-to-a-process-linux